# How to stop Eclipse from "italizing" text in the text editor?

Tags: eclipse, language-agnostic, ide, settings

Hi all I was wondering if it is possible for eclipse to stop "italizing" the words in the editor?

These are my settings for General >> Appearance >> Colors and Fonts:

[image]

I've selected "Regular" style, however in eclipse it shows as this:

[image]

as can be seen, the `BEST_DISPLAY_MODES` and `getBestDisplayMode` are italized. Is there anyway to change that font to "regular" font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the settings for Java syntax highlighting (and similarly for other languages) got to Window->Preferences.  From there expand Java->Editor->Syntax Coloring.  There you will see options for colors and styles for each type of token that is colorized/styled.  You should be able to fix it there.

[image]